# Как отфильтровать данные и поставить условие на date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть запрос такого вида

```
Сущность.where(calendars: {date: "1.07.2015"}).count
```

Мне возвращает количество записей с значением "1.07.2015" в поле date. Но мне надо запрашивать именно 7й месяц (или любой другой). Как отфильтровать и поставить условие на date?

Вот код самой миграции

```
create_table :calendar do |t|           
  t.belongs_to :user, index: true
  t.belongs_to :days_info, index: true
  t.datetime :date
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: Вас интересует запрос в БД на 7-ой месяц конкретного (произвольного на уровне приложения) года, или любого? Последнее существенно сложнее.

Comment: Планирую задавать один из 12ти месяцев цифрой и получать данные за этот месяц.

Comment: И год тоже задавать, само число месяца не нужно по сути.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
What.where(calendars: {date: '1.07.2015'.to_date...'1.07.2015'.to_date + 1.month}).count
```

Comment: Вот так, только, будет только чуть более универсально и чище:
'1.07.2015'.to_date.beginning_of_month..'1.07.2015'.to_date.end_of_month

Comment: Хм, у меня ноль, хотя значения есть, с моим же запросом на первое число count > 0.

Comment: @ks_on_v а какой тип данных у поля `date`? А лучше добавьте миграции в вопрос.

Comment: create_table :calendar do |t|   
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :days_info, index: true
      t.datetime :date
      t.timestamps
 end

Comment: @ks_on_v а попробуйте для обоих запросов, вместо `.count` написать `.to_sql`, и посмотреть, какие запросы генерируются.

Comment: SELECT "days_infos".* FROM "days_infos" INNER JOIN "calendars" ON "days_infos"."id" = "calendars"."days_info_id" WHERE "calendars"."user_id" = ? AND ("calendars"."date" BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31') Вроде то. У меня такая база, https://neepic.com/znoEJNWl , у calendar еще date поле есть.

Comment: Надо ли index в бд добавлять?

Comment: @ks_on_v желательно внешние ключи в таблицах делать индексами. Но на логику работы запросов это никак не влияет. Только на скорость выборки.

Comment: А зачем вообще индексы нужны?

Comment: @ks_on_v чтобы выборка быстрее выполнялась.

Comment: Таким образом я могу все поля индексами сделать и не париться...

Comment: @ks_on_v вам сюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81_(%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Comment: Я понял, запрос почему-то считает, что ячейка типа char. Потому что если запрашивать '1.07.2015', то значения приходят, а если '1.07.2015'.to_date то ничего....Как быть?
Массив строк для получения значений не вариант отправлять...

Comment: @ks_on_v если в миграции указано, что `t.datetime :date`, то всё должно быть нормально. Если, конечно, таблица создавалась по этой миграции.

Comment: Да вроде все правильно, но интервалы не работают. А запросы одинаковые, только концом отличаются (одна дата или интервал)

Comment: Вот два запроса, первый не работает, второй работает:
 1) SELECT "days_infos".* FROM "days_infos" INNER JOIN "calendars" ON "days_infos"."id" = "calendars"."days_info_id" WHERE "calendars"."user_id" = ? AND ("calendars"."date" BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-31')
 2) SELECT "days_infos".* FROM "days_infos" INNER JOIN "calendars" ON "days_infos"."id" = "calendars"."days_info_id" WHERE "calendars"."user_id" = ? AND "calendars"."date" = '1.07.2015'

Answer (score 1):

```
date = '1.07.2015'
daterange = date.to_datetime.beginning_of_month..date.to_datetime.end_of_month
Item.includes(:calendars).where(calendars: {date: daterange}).count
```

Comment: Запрос вроде правильный: SELECT "days_infos".* FROM "days_infos" INNER JOIN "calendars" ON "days_infos"."id" = "calendars"."days_info_id" WHERE "calendars"."user_id" = ? AND ("calendars"."date" BETWEEN '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-07-31 23:59:59.000000'). Но count все равно 0.

Comment: Может по коду я сделал не так, что-то? Хотя запрос current_user.days_info.where(calendars: {date: '1.07.2015'}).count работает, значит зависимости правильно указаны....

Comment: @ks_on_v Что за СУБД? У вас же поле date типа datetime, если просто строку даешь как она находит запись?

Comment: SQLite. В смысле просто строку даешь?

Answer (score 1):

В общем удалил поле date:datetime и создал два поля month:integer и year:integer. Да избыточности много....